# How can I get the tag name in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Is there a way to get the name of the tag of a Selenium web element?

I found, there is `.getTagName()` in selenium for Java, in *[How do I get a parent HTML Tag with Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-get-a-parent-html-tag-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)*.

Example: In this HTML, if I iterate though *class='some_class_name'*, how can I get the tag_name (`h2`,  `p`, `ul` or `li`)?

```html
<div class='some_class_name'>
    <h2>Some Random Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>

    <h2>Some Random Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <p>Random list are:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Python code may look like this...

```
content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='some_class_name']//child::*")
for c in content:
    print(c.getTagName()) # Something like this to get the
                          # tag of inner content...
```

Comment: Sure you can: ```driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')``` Makre sure to use ```elements```instead of ```element```in order to get all ```li``` tags

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but I did not want that. I have edited the question.

Comment: Hey @AnupaM it might help if you give an example of what you expect to find given your example. I'm not following what you mean by `tag Name` is that the inner HTML?

Comment: @DanielButler I have made an edit, Hope I am clear now, and will get any solution.

Comment: Ahh it seems like the problems lies in getting the tag names for elements nested in what the selector finds so in this example the `li`s. Is that accurate?

Comment: That is also true. How can I get tag_names for tags which are not nested. I mean `h` or `p` tags??  When I tried `.getTagName()` using Python, I says, `'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'getTagName'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Python, you have `tag_name` to get the tag name.

```
content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='some_class_name']//child::*")
for c in content:
    print(c.tag_name)
```