# Detect a tag using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

When I use

```
thumbnails = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'thumbnails')
```

and iterate through it's children, how can I detect the tag like `div` or `a`? Example structure:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
   <div class="section">Section 1</div>
   <a href="#">Link 1.1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 1.2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 1.3</a>
   <a href="#">Link 1.4</a>
   <div class="section">Section 2</div>
   <a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2.2</a>
   <div class="section">Section 3</div>
   <a href="#">Link 3.1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3.2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3.3</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3.4</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3.5</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3.6</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3.7</a>
</div>
```

I need to create a json object like below:

```
[
   {
      "section_name": section_name,
      "links": a_tags_list
   }
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324688/how-to-get-tag-name-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 1):

```
thumbnails = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'thumbnails')

a_tags_list=[x.text for x in thumbnails.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')]
```

Not sure if you want the `text` or `get_attribute('outerhtml')`

But you could just use the element thumbnails and find elements from there.

If you want to grab all the children with the tags div or a tag.

```
allChildren=thumbnails.find_elements(By.XPATH,'./a | ./div')
```

you can then loop this and check if it has an href attribute.

```
for child in allChildren:
    if child.get_attribute('href'):
        a_tags_list.append(child.get_attribute('href'))
    else:
        #stuff
```

Comment: I'd like to create an array of objects like in the json above. But since the `sections` have always different number of `links`, the best option would be to iterate through the children of `thumbnails` and see - if a tag is `div` then `section_name =  element.text`, if `a`, then `a_tags_list.append(a.get_attribute('href'))`, if another `div`, then add `section` to the main array, new section object's `section_name = new_name`, `a_tags_list = []` and append next links until new `section` detected and repeat

Comment: So you mean in order xpath transversal. Which you can just .//a or .//div as it's xpath and then append if it has a href attribute or noth.